# Spring cloud - Resttemplate doesn't get injected in interceptor

Tags: java, spring-boot, interceptor, resttemplate, spring-cloud-netflix

I created a resttemplate in my spring boot application like this:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

@LoadBalanced
@Bean
  RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
  }
}
```

This works fine in all classes when autowired. However, in my interceptor, this throws up nullpointer exception.

What could be the reason and how can I configure a loadbalanced (using Ribbon) resttemplate in my interceptor?

Update:

my interceptor:

```
 public class MyInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

  @Autowired
  RestTemplate restTemplate;

  public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
    throws Exception {

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    ...
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);

    //restTemplate is null here
    ResponseEntity<String> result = 
    restTemplate.exchange("<my micro service url using service name>", 
                          HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
    ...

    return true;
}
```

Interceptor is added to spring boot application like this:

```
@Configuration  
public class MyConfigAdapter extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter  {

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
   registry.addInterceptor(new MyInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/*");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show more about your interceptor. There's not enough information to answer.

Comment: @spencergibb, added my code. I can confirm it works fine if I create a new RestTemplate (not loadbalanced) in my interceptor and use "my microservice url and port number" instead of service name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstand how `@Autowired` works.  As soon as you `new MyInterceptor()` outside of a `@Bean` method, it will not get autowired.

Do something like below:

```
@Configuration  
public class MyConfigAdapter extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter  {

    @Autowired
    MyInterceptor myInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(myInterceptor).addPathPatterns("/*");
    }
}
```

Comment: absolutely right. That opened my eyes a little on how spring works. Had to add @Component to my interceptor to make autowiring work.